# Character like á becomes a � in deployed Blazor app. How to fix?

Tags: docker-compose, blazor

Character like á becomes a � in deployed Blazor app.
When I run it locally or using Docker Desktop, no issue.
When I deploy / run it on my target (Synology NAS) it display's the á as a question mark when it is passed through Blazor binding.

What is going on / how to fix this?

[image: image of page + code]

Comment: I don't think that's a Blazor issue.  I think it's a rtf-8 / unicode issue.  Make sure you are using a font that support the additional symbols.

Comment: I can copy the character from Visual Studio to the webpage, and then it is oké.
It seems it will be 'misformated' in the rendering of razor to html.
Also, when I save the item with the correct character, it stays correct.

Comment: Careful with this copying and pasting, though.  I've done that for unicode symbols (arrows etc.) and then had it fail when I accessed the site from a mobile device.  You'll have to take careful steps to make sure that the end user is getting the right symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I guess ... it can be related to differences in character encoding settings between your local environment and the deployment environment. Check your encoding settings. Both should be set to the same character encoding.

Comment: I thought the C# code is platform independent, I don't know how to set or change encoding settings. related to this particular case..